# Get root of website from NSString or NSUrl

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurl

Any ideas how I can get the root of a website from an NSString or an NSURL? So if my URL was  **http://www.foo.com/bar/baragain** how would I get **http://www.foo.com/**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using `[url scheme]` and `[url host]` like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.foo.com/bar/baragain"];
NSLog(@"Base url: %@://%@", [url scheme], [url host]);
// output is http://www.foo.com
```

Comment: this is not universal as there can be username and password too …
this is better solution : “Another way I found to do it is that NSURL contains a path method. I can get the path, and subtract it from the full URL, and I am left with what I want."

Comment: Yeah subtracting the path is safer in case there was a port in there too

Answer (score 10):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.foo.com/bar/baragain"];
NSURL *root = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/" relativeToURL:url];
NSLog(@"root = '%@'", root.absoluteString); // root = 'http://www.foo.com/'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `NSURL`'s `path` from the string. This accounts for port numbers and other data that are part of the root site.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.foo.com/bar/baragain";
NSURL *rootUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *rootUrlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:rootUrl.path withString:@""];
```

Comment: @Hafthor you're right - this is still incorrect. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.foo.com/bar/baragain"; 
NSArray *temp = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @".com"];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", [temp objectAtIndex:0], @".com"];
```

Comment: Can anyone please let me know for downvoting my answer

Comment: Why this was downvoted? It is just wrong, imagine a url like `http://www.computer.com/` Btw, it wasn't me.

Comment: sherry, I didn't downvote you. I do agree with fluchtpunkt though, your solution doesn't resolve anything other than .com however, I wasn't very clear I needed that in my question. The example I gave could lead you to think I only wanted it for .coms.

Comment: Thats fine.I am also in the learning process.I appreciate people correcting us here , if we are wrong somewhere

Comment: A good solution should be able to resolve things like `ftp://user:pass@whatever.here.host.org:8080`.